# Angular Material Datepicker - Initial date styling

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, datepicker

I want to change the styles of the today-date cell when the datepicker is opened and focused for the first time.

Right now, when I open the datepicker, the today-date cell has the following style:

[image]

As you can see, the 14th day cell has the default material background color applied.

I want to change this specific property. However, when I try to inspect this element, the class is not found since the datepicker focus is lost (the background-color disappears, leaving only the border on the cell).

I have tried playing around with `.mat-calendar-body-today:focus` or `.mat-calendar-body-hover` but neither of them seem to access the today-date when it is initially focused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `.mat-calendar-body-selected`?

Comment: @sekthor I have. `.mat-calendar-body-selected` seems to only be used when the user explicitly selects a date.

Comment: `mat-focus-indicator` sounds promising as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up from alin's answer, the table cell class `.mat-calendar-body-active` grabbed my attention.

Indeed, this is the class that should be used in combination with `.mat-calendar-body-today`, as opposed to `.mat-calendar-body-selected`.

I managed to access the today-date cell when datepicker is first focused like so:

```
/* SCCS alternative */
.mat-calendar-body-active {
    .mat-calendar-body-today {
        color: red;
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

/* CSS alternative */
.mat-calendar-body-active > .mat-calendar-body-today {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it works for me

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell:not(.mat-calendar-body-disabled) {

        &.mat-calendar-body-active {
          &:focus {
            .mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected).mat-focus-indicator.mat-calendar-body-today {
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.04);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Absolute legend! Thank you. For the rest of the people who are struggling with the Angular Material 15's previously selected value color, all you have to do is:
```.mat-calendar-body-cell:not(.mat-calendar-body-disabled) {
  &.mat-calendar-body-active {
    &:focus {
      .mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(
          .mat-calendar-body-selected
        ).mat-focus-indicator {
        color: white !important;
      }
    }
  }
}```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```
<td role="gridcell" class="mat-calendar-body-cell mat-calendar-body-active ng-star-inserted" tabindex="0" data-mat-row="2" data-mat-col="5" aria-label="January 14, 2022" aria-selected="true" aria-current="date" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;">
<div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content mat-focus-indicator mat-calendar-body-selected mat-calendar-body-today"> 14 </div>
<div aria-hidden="true" class="mat-calendar-body-cell-preview"></div>
</td>
```

and this is the class that you want to update

```
.mat-calendar-body-selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

So you might combine this `.mat-calendar-body-selected`  with `.mat-calendar-body-today`

Comment: While your answer is not what I'm looking for, the `.mat-calendar-body-active` class on the table cell grabbed my attention. Indeed, this is the class that should be used in combination with `.mat-calendar-body-today`, as opposed to `.mat-calendar-body-selected`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70713530/15822615).